# C++ getline() can't read file

Tags: c++

I want to use C++ to read an XML file, but when I type the following:

```
char infile[] = "util_sip.xml";
ifstream in(infile);
char buffer[256];
assert(in.si_open());

while(!in.eof()){
    in.getline(buffer, 256);
    cout<<buffer<endl;
}
```

It doesn't work and it prints nothing on my screen and causes an infinite loop.
However, if I type:

```
while(in.getline(buffer,strsize)){
    cout<<buffer<<endl;
}
```

It works again. I don't know why it doesn't work when I run the first example.

Comment: I don't know if it is the cause of your particular problem, but the `!in.eof()` loop is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong